# Doctrine slows down performance

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

Application: Symfony3.4

ORM: Doctrine2

(I also can give you web server configuration)

I have performance problem caused by doctrine[image: i.stack.imgur.com/7B024.png]

Query execution time is 1685.69 ms [image: i.stack.imgur.com/VBEJt.png]

Then I've run the same query through MySQL console and got different performance result (115 ms) [image: i.stack.imgur.com/1lNgv.png]

Any guesses?

Answer (score 2):

If you execute the same query, first from doctrine and then directly. Then the query cache will make the second query run very fast.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I've tried many variations, but I'm always getting same (big) difference.
Can I run that through MySQL console without using query cache?
Just to be sure

Comment: You can use the SQL_NO_CACHE keyword if you use mysql 5.7+

Like this:
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM TABLE

Comment: There must be a difference in the query then, can you try to display the full query?

Comment: are you sure that doctrine doesn't load any other entities that cause the load time to be higher? it might happen behind the scenes. It would be very strange that the same query should have different load times

Comment: I guess so and profiler said so...
I doubt I have bad php configuration for doctrine, memory limit or something like that

Comment: if you extract the connection from doctrine and run the "raw" sql there, is it still fast?

Comment: Very good idea!
I just did like that the result: https://imgur.com/a/CgPfm

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what caused difference.

I was using PHPStorm's database console.

I tried to run the query through terminal and got same (slow) result.

The hard part of the query was `CASE` s in `WHERE` statement.

I changed `CASE` with `IFNULL(p0_.updated_at, p0_.created_at)` (query was still heavy)

Finally tried next: `WHERE p0_.created_at >= '2018-01-02 00:00:00' AND p0_.created_at <= '2018-01-02 23:59:59'` (and got result in about 100 ms)

I don't know what PHP Storm did, but That was weird.

Thank you for your attention @frederik-banke-sørensen !